# how to get phone number from SMS android

Tags: android

I am doing one application, and because of security, I need to know that the application has a phone number.

I would like to know if it is possible to take the phone number which has received the SMS from the SMS (not the sending one... I would like to know which number RECIEVES the sms).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the message uri for sent message table,

content://sms/sent

read it and get address column  value... you will get all the sent messages and the numbers on which the messages sent.
you can do

Cursor cr= resolver.quer(Uri.parse(content://sms/sent),--------)

cr.getColumnNames() // by this method you will have all the column available in this uri. read whatever you want

Comment: I dnt think this is working.....What i want is ONLY to recieve SMS on my phone. I have one BroadCastReceiver, and it gets activated when I recieve a SMS, so I want to bring data like the body(no problems), the sender of the SMS(no problems) and the receiver of the SMS(this is what i want to know...). Thanks anyway!

Comment: you want to know your number, which do not get stored anywhere in the database.

Comment: Exactly, I want to know my number, i was checking everywhere on the Android documentation and i can´t find how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

you will need readphone permision

Comment: This is not working with every carrier. In my case, i tried and it returns "null". Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, i did it, but anyway it returns me "null". I was reading on the Android documentation and there are carriers whose SIM cards don´t let read it. In my case, it always return me "null".